# React Routing in Javascript without <Link>

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I understand in react to route to another view, we can use something like below

```
<li><Link to={'/'} className="nav-link"> Home </Link></li>
```

But i would like to route to another route in a js method.

Please let me know if its possible.

Comment: Please checkout the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) for `react-router`'s `useHistory`. If in a class component, [`withRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) can help you accomplish the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use history props if you want to go to Home page
this.props.history.push("/") U need to call this inside class component for function props.history.push("/")